# Custom database role

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a role for some users to be able to create, modify, and delete their own views.  To keep track of what they can work with, I was thinking about a naming convention with a specific prefix, such as 'MYVIEW_'. But I'm not sure how to write a GRANT statement to accomplish this.   Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you would need to give them all their own schema and give them select and view definition permission on their schema.

Comment: I agree with Blam. A schema would be an excellent way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [DDL triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx). A DDL trigger happens whenever a modification of the DB schema is being done. (DDL = Data Definition Language, i.e. the part of T-SQL language that allow to create, alter, delete, etc. all kind of db objects like tables, views, indices, triggers... i.e. anything that alters the DB schema)

Inside the DDL trigger you can see the user name, the attempted command and so on, and roll back the operation depending on who the user is and what he is doing. Here you can see [how to get the user name, databae, schema and object names, and other info of the executed DDL command](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/).

Remember that making `ROLLBACK` is enough to abort the DDL operation, i.e. avoid changes.

In this way you can restrict what a particular user can do. You can also create a table with users and what they can do, and look the permissions of the users from the trigger code. In this way you can use a single trigger for several users, and make it more maintainable. I.e., in your trigger code, look for the user in that table to see if it's necessary to apply the control.

It's advisable to `PRINT` a message if the user is not allowed to do an operation, to inform him why.